# Ideas for EJB-based project

Tags: java, ejb

I'm starting learning EJBs and would like to explore it by creating a toy project, where I could understand concepts and get hand in base tools like stateless beans, integration with persistence layer and so on. The problem is in finding **good idea** for such a project. Here are some requirements:

- The project must be taken **from real life**. No examples like calculator or getting server's time, please.
- It must show **advantages of EJBs**.
- It must use **at least 2 EJB features**. For instance, integration with JPA and JMS, but not pure logic. What is the reason for EJBs if you don't use its cool features?
- It **must not** take **too much time to implement**. It's a toy project, I don't want to expand 2 months in doing something, that will be thrown out later.

So, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best recommendation would always be to create something that you would find useful and interesting.  It'll keep your motivation up.

If you still can't think of something, I'd recommend a calendar or address book.  I can see where there'd be a clear layered architecture (services + persistence), a variety of views (desktop and web and mobile), and the possibility of using messaging to good advantage (e.g., alerts sent for changes).

Answer (score 1):

Famous [Game of Life](http://www.bitstorm.org/gameoflife/) seems to be a good idea. Cells are persistence units, JSF, web beans + ejb to display the working area, scheduled beans  - to put it in motion. Game's logic can be implemented in EJB or JMS (or even both). You could extend original logic, introduce new objects or rules and finally get Nobel prize for achievements in social modeling :)